# Joomla Editor stripping <p> elements

Tags: html, tinymce, joomla3.0

The joomla (3.3) TinyMCE  Editor is stripping my

elements and only leaving all text as one paragraph with one set of the paragraph tags, anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please enhance your question with some code, your configuration and what you tried to fix this problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to install Joomla JCE Editor component. Its really good and free and it will also fix your problem

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads

Comment: Thank you, I installed JCE, but how di I make it the default editor?

Comment: Go to  Global Configuration. On the Global Config page under Default Editor *: select - Editor JCE and save. You can also go to JCE editor and edit the profile to your requirment. Just go to Components > JCE editor > Editor profile